# Why -92233720368.5478

Tags: database, oracle, excel, vba

I am having **value < - 92233720368.5478** in an oracle table and I am fetching the data through VB code and displaying the value in an excel file. But every time the value is displayed in excel as - 92233720368.5478.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Could it be an overflow situation you are talking about?

Comment: Why not? what is the actual value of value?

Comment: Are you using VB or VBA? They are not the same. In either case please show us the _actual_ code you are using.

Comment: This number is 2^63-1 divided by 100,000,000, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807 - so it does look fishy. What is the expected value?

Comment: Please show your VB or VBA code as I can confirm that there is no problem in importing < - 92233720368.5478. It is imported exactly same on my computer.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field in the Oracle table? My bet is that it's a 64 bit field with exactly 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but it seems you have reached the minValue for the Long DataType, (followed by some formatting in your sheet maybe) :

VBA converts all integer values to type Long (source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754.aspx)

see the MinValue for Long : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx

It looks pretty much like the value you're getting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A `Long` isn't the same in VB and VBA. The Min value in VBA is actually -2,147,483,648 because a Long in VBA is only 4 bytes